# How to change from using Hibernate in project to only Postgres JDBC

Tags: postgresql, hibernate, jdbc

I need to transition a project from Hibernate (ORM) to direct JDBC interactions with a PostgreSQL database. How do I do that and is there any step-by-step approach to replace the Hibernate functionality with JDBC code?

I tried to write a PostgresDAO but it looks almost identical to the HibernateDAO consisting of CRUD methods.

Comment: Welcome to the SO community. The community will help you with issues, but there are some expectation of you. Please spend a few minuets to [Take the Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and review [ask]. If you have a specific question then by all means post it. However this is just way too broad as subject for SO.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.